# How to delete a package from MyGet Symbols Server

Tags: myget

I have tried using nuget.exe delete command with source and api key but it returns NotFound Exception
Is there any way to delete one or multiple symbols packages

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting a package through the MyGet Website.

I then pushed the same package again, and the .nupkg uploaded without any problems.

However the symbols.nupkg file didn't upload, saying that it already existed.

Based on this very simple analysis it looks like a myget problem to me.